# How show stars in snippts?

Tags: structured-data

i have add itemprop too my code for rating value, but it does not show in my snippt(the stars), what should i do? does it take time?

```
      <div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating" title="Rate"  + " : " + hidContentRate.Value %>" >
   <span itemprop="ratingValue"><%= hidContentRate.Value %></span>
</div>
```